# Unable to Retrieve Directory Using ProFTPD(WHM)

Tags: ftp, whm, pureftpd

Well, after looking for many solutions. I came here now.
I am setting up WHM/cPanel for hosting website. Everything was going smooth but I am stuck on FTP connection (Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.)

Server Details:
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
WHM/cPanel Version 11.58.0.13
FTP Server: PureFTPD

[Acutal error while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3TeY.jpg)

Comment: It seems firewall blocking connection, have you installed any firewall over WHM?

Comment: Thanks @SachinG. I have FirewallD in WHM but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue and get FTP working you need to open up more numbered ports so FTP can connect. I assume you are using CSF.

Login to WHM then go to CSF >> Firewall Configuration >>

[image]

`allow TCP_In 30000:50000 and TCP_Out 30000:50000`

Once you made the changes Restart the firewall

Now you need to make changes in FTP config file to use these ports, you will find this file to this location `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf`

Now you will see a line as follows and you will need to uncomment it

```
# Port range for passive connections replies. - for firewalling.
PassivePortRange          30000 50000
```

Restart FTP Service and should work.